# Which is the best practice when replacing a system binary?

Tags: package-management, osx, path, directory-structure

I'm working on Mac OS X which is shipped with several binaries mostly located in `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/sbin/`. Since it doesn't have a native package manager like some Linux distros, I got used to managing my own binaries, building and installing in `/usr/local/<package_name>/`.

This way, I am able to fully remove a package from my system at the cost of manually update the `PATH` and the `MANPATH` variables in the `.bashrc` file.

Here is a simple example:

Mac OS X ships with ant 1.7.0, located in `/usr/bin`. I need to use the latest version, so I download it from Apache and then unzip (build) it to `/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.2`. Then I update my `.bashrc` file with:

```
# Mac OS X original PATH
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
# Apache Ant 1.8.2
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin"
export PATH
```

I make sure to export the `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/sbin/` before the `ant/bin/` because there are often other binaries besides the `ant` that I don't want to override.

The problem is that when I type `which ant` I get `/usr/bin/`. So I rename the `/usr/bin/ant` to `/usr/bin/ant-old` in order to work with the latest build.

While this works, I want to know if there are better approaches to replacing a system binary (mainly to avoid the last rename).

Comment: Do you know about MacPorts and Fink?  If not, look them up -- they're 3rd party package managers for OS X and might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing a system binary should be a last resort.

My advice is to:

- Put `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` and other system directories on the `PATH`.
- Make `/usr/local/bin/ant` a symbolic link to `/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant`.
- Don't include `/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin` in the `PATH` at all.

This way:

- Your customizations (in `/usr/local/bin`) override the system defaults.
- The symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/ant` reminds you where you got that version of `ant`.
- If you want to test something with the default setup, just remove `/usr/local/bin` from your `PATH` for the duration of the test.

Answer (score 4):

The usual method of overriding system binaries is to install the new binaries in `/usr/local/bin` (or `sbin`) and then making sure that `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in your path.

Normally, you do that by configuring packages with `--prefix=/usr/local`, which causes them to install their binaries under `/usr/local/bin`, instead of making a directory in `/usr/local` for each package.

Are you saying there are binaries in `/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin` that you don't want to use?  In that case, I'd recommend installing it under `/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.2` (as you're doing now), but then making a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` to `../apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant` (instead of putting `/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin` in your path).